# Saving a txt file to removable drive with c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, drive

I have looked everywhere, but have found nothing that is right for what I am after.

I am making a utility for my LED lights. I need to save a text file named hy.txt onto my SD card. Obviously, depending on what you have plugged in the drive letter can change every time. So I have renamed my SD card to STAR-LIGHT.

I have no idea how to search for the name, I have, however, only seen people looking for the drive letter.

I'm not sure if this makes much sense. Please feel free to ask me any questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331043/get-list-of-connected-usb-devices have you checked this out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "might" work (only tried with a USB drive and my HDD partitions):

```
string[] drives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();
foreach (string drive in drives)
{
    try
    {
        DriveInfo di = new DriveInfo(drive);
        if (di.VolumeLabel == "STAR-LIGHT")
        {
            // code
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I am trying to do this, but I can't figure out how to add the text file to the drive. How would I go about that? any ideas?

Comment: @Lee Denbigh: Do you have the file on some other drive, or do you want to generate it from the program?

Comment: I have the file on the removable drive, but I would like to create it if it is missing.

Comment: Thanks mate. I must of been being dopey when I asked that, becasue it was totally straight forward. I just saved it to "drive". Thanks a lot for that!

Comment: @Lee Denbigh: No problem. Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.