# win32_USBDevice is missging from Win32 Classes

Tags: c#-4.0, usb, wmi, device

I am trying to retrieve PID and VID of a connected USB device. Starting with this line of C# code:

```
System.Management.ManagementClass USBClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_USBDevice");
```

Then I got exception `"ManagementException not found"`, Later I run into this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394084(v=vs.85).aspx

It turned out `Win32_USBDevice` was not on the list at all. Tried `Win32_USBController` but didn't get what I wanted. Could anyone let me know if there is any substitute class on the list to extract PID and VID of a connected USB device?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `Win32_USBControllerDevice`?

Comment: Looks it doesn't fit the bill. Here is the definition of it:class  <br/> Win32_USBControllerDevice : CIM_ControlledBy
{
  uint16            AccessState;
  CIM_USBController REF Antecedent;
  CIM_LogicalDevice REF Dependent;
  uint32            NegotiatedDataWidth;
  uint64            NegotiatedSpeed;
  uint32            NumberOfHardResets;
  uint32            NumberOfSoftResets;
};

Comment: Sorry for unreadable format. Doesn't know how to change lines in the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`System.Management.ManagementClass USBClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_USBHub");`

Answer (score 0):

Use Win32_PnPEntity.  You can get the both the PID and VID of connected USB devices from Win32_PnPEntity by parsing the "PNPDeviceID".

Start with this example: [Get List of connected USB Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331043/get-list-of-connected-usb-devices)