# How to find USB device list by using C#.NET

Tags: c#, usb

I want a list of connected USB Device in C#.NET. but I can't understand what to do.

Comment: have you even tried to search for a solution? what about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331043/get-list-of-connected-usb-devices just type your question into google...

Comment: I need to show it in a list box. I've seen your link before. but some code do not work.

Error 1 The name 'GetUSBDevices' does not exist in the current context G:\USB_Device_List\USB_Device\USB_Device\Form1.cs 25 34 USB_Device

Comment: @MarufHossain: the GetUSBDevices() is defined just below the Main function.

Answer (score 3):

Add a reference to System.Management in  project,After that refer code

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management; // need to add System.Management to your project references.

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var usbDevices = GetUSBDevices();

        foreach (var usbDevice in usbDevices)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Device ID: {0}", usbDevice.DeviceID);

        }

        Console.Read();
    }

    static List<USBDeviceInfo> GetUSBDevices()
    {
        List<USBDeviceInfo> devices = new List<USBDeviceInfo>();

        ManagementObjectCollection collection;
        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_USBHub"))
            collection = searcher.Get();

        foreach (var device in collection)
        {
            devices.Add(new USBDeviceInfo(
            (string)device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID")
            ));
        }

        collection.Dispose();
        return devices;
    }
}

class USBDeviceInfo
{
    public USBDeviceInfo(string deviceID)
    {
        this.DeviceID = deviceID;
    }
    public string DeviceID { get; private set; }

}
```

}

Hope it helps you.