# C# get com port connected to USB device

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, port

How to get the com ports on which usb dongal modem is connected in C# program. Neeed quick help.

In actual, i want to send SMS. For sending SMS ,it needs to identify the port which is connected to USB Modem.

Comment: bhau he refer kara : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331043/get-list-of-connected-usb-devices?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @ShrimantBajiraoPeshawe-I bhau maley gmail id deya..