# How do I query for USB devices not listed in USB Root Hub

Tags: wmi

Query which works for some devices found in **Win32_USBHub**

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_USBHub WHERE DeviceID = '{0}'
```

Here's the code context,

```
// Check if USB device is plugged in
string deviceQuery = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_USBHub WHERE DeviceID = '{0}'", deviceID);
using (var searcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(deviceQuery))
    if (searcher.Get().Count == 0)
        MessageBox.Show(@"Device not detected");
```

However when a device is not listed inside 'Universal Serial Bus controllers', querying from `Win32_USBHub` does not return the connected device I'm looking for.

[image: USB Device]

Is there another 'table' to query outside from `Win32_USBHub` which would contain device I'm looking for 'Cardio Perfect PRO-Link USB'? Or would this be a 'custom table'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE DeviceID = '{0}'
```

I guess I didn't search long enough, here's a link which contains a lot of really good examples...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The 'table' I was looking for is `Win32_PnPEntity` it listed all 155 devices I'm connected to.

Comment: I had to use "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity" but it listed Windows Portable Devices (aka MTP: Media Transport Protocol) which include Android devices.