# Detect only connected USB mouse(s) to computer

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, io, usb, mouse

I want to detect no. of mouse(s) connected to the computer. But currently the below code (reference:[Get List of connected USB Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331043/get-list-of-connected-usb-devices))  detects both connected USB mouse and Keyboard(May be any USB input device/composite device).

But I only want mouse to be detected by in program.

How do I do that.
Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Management;

    namespace ConsoleApplication2_0
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var usbDevices = GetUSBDevices();
                Console.WriteLine("Total USB Mouse : " + usbDevices.Count);
                Console.Read();
            }

            static List<USBDeviceInfo> GetUSBDevices()
            {
                List<USBDeviceInfo> devices = new List<USBDeviceInfo>();

                ManagementObjectCollection collection;


                using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_USBHub"))
                    collection = searcher.Get();

                foreach (var device in collection)
                {               
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------");
                    //if ((string)device.GetPropertyValue("Description") == "USB Mass Storage Device")
                    if ((string)device.GetPropertyValue("Description") == "USB Composite Device")
                    {                    
                        Console.WriteLine("__RELPATH\t" + device.GetPropertyValue("__RELPATH").ToString());

                        foreach (var mouseprop in device.Properties)
                        {

                            if (mouseprop.Value != null)
                                Console.WriteLine(mouseprop.Name.ToString() + "\t" + mouseprop.Value.ToString());
                        }
                        devices.Add(new USBDeviceInfo(
                           (string)device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID"),
                           (string)device.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID"),
                           (string)device.GetPropertyValue("Description")
                           ));
                    }
                }

                collection.Dispose();
                return devices;
            }
        }

        class USBDeviceInfo
        {
            public USBDeviceInfo(string deviceID, string pnpDeviceID, string description)
            {
                this.DeviceID = deviceID;
                this.PnpDeviceID = pnpDeviceID;
                this.Description = description;
            }
            public string DeviceID { get; private set; }
            public string PnpDeviceID { get; private set; }
            public string Description { get; private set; }
        }
    }
```