# How to make my application run automatically when USB drive is plugged in?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, usb-drive

Im currently doing an application for my school project.
How can i make the application when the user insert the USB drive into
usb port, the login form will automatically pop out asking user to 
login first and if success, user can use the USB drive(usb port will be enabled).
Im using windows 7,vb.net 2010, my application name is PutLock and this app
will be installed in drive C. Thanks ^^

Comment: You could use code to detect if USB are connected and go from there:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225170/failed-to-detect-usb)

Comment: This article is an interesting read, which might be of some help: [link](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/autorun-usb-flash-drive.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution on internet, THIS CODE IS NOT MINE!
But damn, it works really well:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
```

Public Class Form1

```
Private Const WM_DEVICECHANGE As Integer = &H219
Private Const DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL As Integer = &H8000
Private Const DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME As Integer = &H2

'Device information structure
Public Structure DEV_BROADCAST_HDR
    Public dbch_size As Int32
    Public dbch_devicetype As Int32
    Public dbch_reserved As Int32
End Structure

'Volume information Structure
Private Structure DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME
    Public dbcv_size As Int32
    Public dbcv_devicetype As Int32
    Public dbcv_reserved As Int32
    Public dbcv_unitmask As Int32
    Public dbcv_flags As Int16
End Structure

'Function that gets the drive letter from the unit mask
Private Function GetDriveLetterFromMask(ByRef Unit As Int32) As Char
    For i As Integer = 0 To 25
        If Unit = (2 ^ i) Then
            Return Chr(Asc("A") + i)
        End If
    Next
End Function

'Override message processing to check for the DEVICECHANGE message
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If m.Msg = WM_DEVICECHANGE Then
        If CInt(m.WParam) = DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL Then
            Dim DeviceInfo As DEV_BROADCAST_HDR
            DeviceInfo = DirectCast(Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, GetType(DEV_BROADCAST_HDR)), DEV_BROADCAST_HDR)
            If DeviceInfo.dbch_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME Then
                Dim Volume As DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME
                Volume = DirectCast(Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, GetType(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)), DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)
                Dim DriveLetter As String = (GetDriveLetterFromMask(Volume.dbcv_unitmask) & ":\")
                If IO.File.Exists(IO.Path.Combine(DriveLetter, "test.txt")) Then
                    '<<<< The test file has been found >>>>
                    MessageBox.Show("Found test file")
                Else
                    '<<<< Test file has not been found >>>>
                    MessageBox.Show("Could not find test file")
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    'Process all other messages as normal
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Obviously here the program check for an existing "test" file on the insert USB Drive.. you need to change your code for your needed

Comment: thank you very mush for the code. of course I will change it ^^