# How to detect whether windows phone is plugged into windows 7 computer?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to make an app that detects whether my Nokia Lumia 520 is plugged into my laptop. 
I've tried looking at:

```
    foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
```

Windows detects the "C" and "D" drives, but not windows phone.

How come windows does not assign a drive letter to this device? When I go to "My computer", what I see is "Computer\Windows Phone".

I've tried:

```
    if(Directory.Exists(@"Computer\Windows Phone"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Found");
    }
```

This it is not signalling to me that there is such a directory.

Comment: You can't access the phone using file system APIs, because it's not mounted on the file system. You need to use the [Media Transport Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) to do it. On Windows 8, WinRT provides a simple API to access MTP devices, but I'm afraid it's going to be significantly harder on Windows 7...

Comment: @Sybren, it has nothing to do with what the OP wants; it's a library to help websites detect mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [Windows Portable Devices APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dd388998.aspx). They provide a [sample application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dd798115.aspx) that enumerates portable devices, but it is in C++. However you can still right a C# application that uses those APIs since they are COM interfaces. Check this [blog-post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dimeby8/archive/2006/12/05/enumerating-wpd-devices-in-c.aspx) that does exactly that (The blog has many other useful posts on this topic).

If you only want to check if the device is connected however, then you could do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331043/get-list-of-connected-usb-devices).