# C# get portable devices connected to PC

Tags: c#, connection, usb, wpd

I am trying to get all usb devices(including portable devices) on Windows 7
now I searched all over and didnt find a good answer.

I tried this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //
    // Get an instance of the device manager
    //
    PortableDeviceApiLib.PortableDeviceManagerClass devMgr
        = new PortableDeviceApiLib.PortableDeviceManagerClass();

    //
    // Probe for number of devices
    //
    uint cDevices = 1;
    devMgr.GetDevices(null, ref cDevices);

    //
    // Re-allocate if needed
    //
    if (cDevices > 0)
    {
        string[] deviceIDs = new string[cDevices];
        devMgr.GetDevices(deviceIDs, ref cDevices);

        for (int ndxDevices = 0; ndxDevices < cDevices; ndxDevices++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Device[{0}]: {1}",
                    ndxDevices + 1, deviceIDs[ndxDevices]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No WPD devices are present!");
    }
}
```

but i get this error:

> interop type 'portabledeviceapilib.portabledevicemanagerclass' Cannot
>   be embedded

Now im pretty stuck.

If you could help me with this code/ give me an idea what should i try, ill be happy

all I need is to get which type of USB got connected,
if a phone is connected, or a mouse. i want to know what is connected.

Thanx Ahead

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331043/get-list-of-connected-usb-devices

Comment: but this does not show me portable device, like my phone...

Answer (score 3):

I am using the NuGet package [PortableDevices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PortableDevices/) (which is based on the [tutorial by Christophe Geers](https://github.com/geersch/WPD)).

Derived from part one of the tutorial:

```
public void ListDevices()
{
    var devices = new PortableDeviceCollection();
    devices.Refresh();

    foreach (var device in devices)
    {
        device.Connect();
        Console.WriteLine(@"DeviceId: {0}, FriendlyName: {1}", device.DeviceId, device.FriendlyName);
        device.Disconnect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on [@CodeFox's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36149905/831138), and in order to make his code `ListDevices()` work:

1. Download the NuGet package [PortableDevices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PortableDevices/)
2. Add references to these 4 COM libraries:

   - PortableDeviceClassExtension
   - PortableDeviceConnectApi
   - PortableDeviceTypes
   - PortableDeviceApi
3. Take the dll's under `obj\Debug` and put them into `bin\Debug`:

   - Interop.PortableDeviceClassExtension.dll
   - Interop.PortableDeviceConnectApiLib.dll
   - Interop.PortableDeviceTypesLib.dll
   - Interop.PortableDeviceApiLib.dll

---

Now you can use this function, although `FriendlyName` does not seem to be working (it returns an empty string):

```
    private IDictionary<string, string> GetDeviceIds()
    {
        var deviceIds = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var devices = new PortableDeviceCollection();
        devices.Refresh();
        foreach (var device in devices)
        {
            device.Connect();
            deviceIds.Add(device.FriendlyName, device.DeviceId);
            Console.WriteLine(@"DeviceId: {0}, FriendlyName: {1}", device.DeviceId, device.FriendlyName);
            device.Disconnect();
        }
        return deviceIds;
    }
```

The next step for me is getting the contents from the device, which is done like so:

```
var contents = device.GetContents();
```

Comment: I haven't found these DLL's under obj\Debug. I am getting File Not Found exception is it beacause of this?