# Can't get directory from external device

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the items from within a folder on an Android phone.

However the FolderBrowserDialog won't let me select a folder from within in the phone. The path looks like this `This PC\Xperia Z3 Compact\SD Card\Music`

To select a folder I'm currently using:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        UserFolderLocation = dlg.SelectedPath;
    }
    else { }
}
```

Then when searching the folder for its contents I use:

```
try
{
    folderItems = Directory.GetFiles(directory).Select(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)).ToArray();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
```

If I insert the path `This PC\Xperia Z3 Compact\SD Card\Music` as a variable then search it, it throws a `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException`.

How do I select and use a path that doesn't begin with `c:`, `d:` etc?

Comment: Please add more info how are you running your code on Android. What frameworks are you using? etc..

Comment: This is a desktop application and the phone it is trying to connect to is running Android 5.1.1. I'm using version 4.5.2 of the .NET framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I ended up using the shell32 library. It has the ability to handle portable devices (That both include and don't include the drive letters).

Include the reference for `shell32.dll`
and include the library:

```
using Shell32;
```

Then instead of using the FolderBrowserDialog I used the use the shell browse for folder. Which returns a strange path for a folder on a phone, for the phone I used to test the path looked like this: 
`::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\?\usb#vid_04e8&pid_6860&ms_comp_mtp&samsung_android#6&fee689d&3&0000#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}\SID-{20002,SECZ9519043CHOHB01,63829639168}\{013C00D0-011B-0130-3A01-380113012901}`

```
public int Hwnd { get; private set; }

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Shell shell = new Shell();
    Folder folder = shell.BrowseForFolder((int)Hwnd, "Choose Folder", 0, 0);     
    if (folder == null)
    {
        // User cancelled
    }
    else
    {             
        FolderItem fi = (folder as Folder3).Self;
        UserFolderLocation = fi.Path;
    }
}
```

Then to select search the folder for its contents:

```
try
{
    Folder dir = shell.NameSpace(directory);

    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    foreach (FolderItem curr in dir.Items())
    {
        list.Add(curr.Name);
    }
    folderItems = list.ToArray();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
```

Comment: When I try the same solution and select my phone (not a directory inside it) everything works, but when I select a folder inside my phone I get a path like this:
::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\\\\?\\usb#vid_04e8&pid_6860&ms_comp_mtp&samsung_android#6&2a1f2d33&0&0000#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}\\SID-{10001,SECZ9519043CHOHB,114301988864}, but getNameSpace() just returns null. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

"This PC" is only there for the eyes of the user - internally it is not used at all. You can see for yourself by applying the first marked setting in Windows Explorer 
[image: screenshot]

Additionally Windows assigns a drive letter to every local device - it just doesn't show it by default. (use the second marked setting to check)

So in reality you have to use (assuming you phone was assigned Drive `F:`) something like `F:\SD Card\Music\`.

Possibly related: [Get List Of Connected USB Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331043/get-list-of-connected-usb-devices) about the ability to find a device without knowing the assigned drive letter.

Comment: Even with these settings enabled the phone still is just listed as "This PC\Xperia Z3 Compact"