# C# shell.NameSpace does not find the folder on an external device

Tags: c#, shell32

I have the following problem:

I am using the Shell32 library to be able to access files even on external devices such as my android phone. Getting a local folder and the Phone itself works, but not the folder on the phone. My current code to get a folder (found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331667/cant-get-directory-from-external-device)):

```cs
Shell shell = new Shell();
Folder folder = shell.BrowseForFolder((int)Hwnd, "Choose Folder", 0, 0);
if (folder != null) {
   FolderItem fi = (folder as Folder3).Self;
   string path = fi.Path;
   //...
}
```

And later I am trying to get the Folder again by using:

```cs
Folder folder = shell.NameSpace(path);
```

which works fine for all local files and the phone itself, but not for the directories on the phone.
The path for a local directory looks like a normal path: `"D:\\Bilder\\Bretagne 2016"`,

the one for the phone:

`"::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\\\\?\\usb#vid_04e8&pid_6860&ms_comp_mtp&samsung_android#6&2a1f2d33&0&0000#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}"`,

which is some identifier, but works and then for a specific directory on my phone:

`"::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\\\\?\\usb#vid_04e8&pid_6860&ms_comp_mtp&samsung_android#6&2a1f2d33&0&0000#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}\\SID-{10001,SECZ9519043CHOHB,114301988864}\\{E398106A-CD20-9A9C-490B-5079C2D70B84}"`

with this path I just get a null object when calling `shell.NameSpace(path);`

Has anyone an idea what I am doing wrong? Have absolutely no idea how to fix this.

Thanks in advance,

Finn

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512737/how-to-manage-files-on-an-mtp-portable-device

Comment: looks like a valid solution for external devices. Gonna use it as a workaround, but it requires me to handle phones and local files separately. Still wondering why my approach does not work

Answer (score 0):

So, found an interesting workaround.

To get a folder on my phone, I can just join the id/path I get from selecting the phone in the `BrowseForFolder` dialog and the human readable path like this:
`::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\\\\?\\usb#vid_04e8&pid_6860&ms_comp_mtp&samsung_android#6&2a1f2d33&0&0000#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}\\Phone\DCIM\Camera` and everything works fine.

Not really an idea why the path you get from `Folder.path` does not work, but this does. As long as there is no other solution this works at least.