# How can I open External memory file as FileStream is c#

Tags: c#, filestream

I have a file on a external device
`This PC\HERO4 Session\External Memory\DCIM\101GOPRO`. Is there a way I can read this file in c# using `File.OpenRead("This PC\HERO4 Session\External Memory\DCIM\101GOPRO")` because when I tried to my desktop WPF app just adds the execution path and fails with `FileNotFoundException`.
Thanks

Comment: "This PC" isn't an actual path on the file system. This other question might help, but it's not an exact duplicate because they're showing a folder browser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331667/cant-get-directory-from-external-device
Still, it gives you an example of what kind of path you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

`\` is a special symbol.

You can use `\\` in string: `File.OpenRead("This PC\\HERO4 Session\\...")`

or

`@` before the string `File.OpenRead(@"This PC\HERO4 Session\...")`

Comment: I tried this approach many times, but as i said when i try to open a file from external drive and the path does not start with a partition like C: or D: then my wpf app just adds the execution path at the start and throws exception