# c# program that reading from usb

Tags: c#

Hi this is program for my graduation project that read from usb but even i connect usb to computer it gives me every  time "Device can't found" please help me

the code:

```
namespace Grad_pro
{
    public class read_data
    {
        public static UsbDevice MyUsbDevice;

        #region SET YOUR USB Vendor and Product ID!

        public static UsbDeviceFinder MyUsbFinder =
            new UsbDeviceFinder(0x0000, 0x0000); // specify vendor, product id

        #endregion

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ErrorCode ec = ErrorCode.None;

            try
            {
                // Find and open the usb device.
                MyUsbDevice = UsbDevice.OpenUsbDevice(MyUsbFinder);

                // If the device is open and ready
                if (MyUsbDevice == null) throw new Exception("Device Not Found.");

                // If this is a "whole" usb device (libusb-win32, linux libusb)
                // it will have an IUsbDevice interface. If not (WinUSB) the
                // variable will be null indicating this is an interface of a
                // device.
                IUsbDevice wholeUsbDevice = MyUsbDevice as IUsbDevice;
                if (!ReferenceEquals(wholeUsbDevice, null))
                {
                    // This is a "whole" USB device. Before it can be used,
                    // the desired configuration and interface must be selected.

                    // Select config
                    wholeUsbDevice.SetConfiguration(1);

                    // Claim interface
                    wholeUsbDevice.ClaimInterface(1);
                }

                // open read endpoint
                UsbEndpointReader reader =
                    MyUsbDevice.OpenEndpointReader(ReadEndpointID.Ep02);

                // open write endpoint
                UsbEndpointWriter writer =
                    MyUsbDevice.OpenEndpointWriter(WriteEndpointID.Ep03);

                // write data, read data
                int bytesWritten;
                ec = writer.Write(new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00 }, 2000, out bytesWritten); // specify data to send

                if (ec != ErrorCode.None)
                    throw new Exception(UsbDevice.LastErrorString);

                byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
                while (ec == ErrorCode.None)
                {
                    int bytesRead;

                    // If the device hasn't sent data in the last 100 milliseconds,
                    // a timeout error (ec = IoTimedOut) will occur.
                    ec = reader.Read(readBuffer, 100, out bytesRead);

                    if (bytesRead == 0) throw new Exception("No more bytes!");

                    // Write that output to the console.
                    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead));
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\r\nDone!\r\n");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine((ec != ErrorCode.None ? ec + ":" : String.Empty) + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (MyUsbDevice != null)
                {
                    if (MyUsbDevice.IsOpen)
                    {
                        // If this is a "whole" usb device (libusb-win32, linux libusb-1.0)
                        // it exposes an IUsbDevice interface. If not (WinUSB) the
                        // 'wholeUsbDevice' variable will be null indicating this is
                        // an interface of a device; it does not require or support
                        // configuration and interface selection.
                        IUsbDevice wholeUsbDevice = MyUsbDevice as IUsbDevice;
                        if (!ReferenceEquals(wholeUsbDevice, null))
                        {
                            // Release interface
                            wholeUsbDevice.ReleaseInterface(1);
                        }

                        MyUsbDevice.Close();
                    }
                    MyUsbDevice = null;

                    // Free usb resources
                    UsbDevice.Exit();

                }

                // Wait for user input..
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get List of connected USB Devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331043/get-list-of-connected-usb-devices)

Comment: from your code: `SET YOUR USB Vendor and Product ID!`

Answer (score 0):

The [LibUsbDotNet](https://github.com/LibUsbDotNet/LibUsbDotNet) library appears to be undergoing some change at the moment. I had no luck with getting any of the older versions of the library to work. However, there is an alpha version that does work. I submitted this [sample](https://github.com/LibUsbDotNet/LibUsbDotNet/blob/master/src/Examples/Read.Write/ReadWrite.cs) to them and it was accepted. It works for the device I am talking to (as long as you add a physical reference to the libusb dll.

However, I don't recommend using LibUsb. LibUSb is just a C wrapper for the standard Windows USB and Hid API calls. This is useful if you want somethign cross platform with Linux, but as far as I know, LibUsb doesn't support other platforms.

I recommend using the [Windows Hid](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/master/src/Hid.Net/Windows/HidAPICalls.cs), and [USB](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/master/src/Usb.Net/Windows/WinUsbApiCalls.cs) APIs directly. These are used part of [Usb.Net and Hid.Net](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/wiki). If you do need to keep your code cross platform with Linux, you can still use an polymorphism to [wrap](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Trezor.Net/blob/LibUsbUnitTest/src/Trezor.Net.LibUsbUnitTest/LibUsbDevice.cs) the LibUsbDotNet library on Linux: