# Get multiple USB devices ID and show them in different textboxes

Tags: c#, usb

is it possible to get multiple USB devices and show them in different textboxes?
I searched some questions here and all of them pointed to show only one device. But I have multiple  USB devices and I´d like to show them in different textboxes. Thank you.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by showing USB devices in text boxes.

Comment: Hi, I need to show USB device in textbox, the USB device info.

Comment: See my previous comment. Eg. do you want to show the device name? Its state? Its internal device id? Data from the device?

Comment: is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331043/get-list-of-connected-usb-devices