# List connected SPI devices with C#

Tags: c#, windows, usb, spi

is there any simple way to get all the devices, which are connected via SPI on Windows?
I know there is a SPI class in C# but i am not able to get this running.
I also know this thread: [Get List of connected USB devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331043/get-list-of-connected-usb-devices), where they use the ManagementObjectCollection for all the usb devices.
But i do not know how to specify the query for the spi devices.

Thank you!
tbockmair

Comment: Is this Windows IoT or Windows PC?

Comment: It is a Windows PC.