# How to dynamically get the devices connected to my system using c#?

Tags: c#, usb

[Get List of connected USB Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331043/get-list-of-connected-usb-devices)

I have tried the above link but it is not dynamically detected it .
I do not want to use any windows procedure (wndproc)  to do it.Any other ways?

Comment: The link _is_ _"dynamic"_.  What has the [Windows Callback Proc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms633573(v%3Dvs.85)) to do with it?

Comment: @MickyD because it listening for Windows message is *the way* to do it... Despite OP wishing not to listen to those events there really is no other way... as everything in Windows is event based. (Obviously one can poll... but that is in no way "dynamically detect")

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ah thank-you good sir.