# How to listen for input from a USB device in VB.net on a VM

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, remote-desktop

I have a program that uses a USB device, I was using the [Raw Input](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard) approach before to interact and listen in on my USB device and everything was working great. However, now in current circumstances everyone is working from home and our organization is using Microsoft remote desktop [application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/windowsdesktop). Now, nothing is being picked up via the raw Input.

On the application(VM), I have the device forwarding working and I can select which USB devices to forward, but again nothing is being picked up.

However, I did some more searching around and I found a post talking about detecting USB Devices ([Get List of connected USB Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331043/get-list-of-connected-usb-devices))
 on your machine and I am able to detect the USB devices when I query against the Win32_PnPEntity , Thus I am able to get the PNPDeviceID and the DeviceID of my device.

Is there a way I can use this information to listen in a USB device? (in VB.net) Or is there a better way other than the Raw Input process? Or maybe the device forwarding is not set up correctly?