# Get list of USB devices in windows

Tags: c, windows, usb

I am attempting to get a list of removable/USB drives connected to a Windows computer. I have tried functions like GetLogicalDrives however I have had no luck. I am looking for an effective method of gathering the USB list

Comment: Your title and question are a bit different.  Do you strictly just want mass storage devices (drives), or do you want *all* USB devices (mice, serial adapters, network devices...)?

Comment: What does "I have had no luck" mean? Didn't the API return useful information or were you unable to get anything working at all?

Comment: check the accepted answer on this answer...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331043/get-list-of-connected-usb-devices

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you asked. It returns all **removable** drives, meaning that it will returns all USB drives, but also everything tagged as "Removable" by Windows - excepted CD-ROM, they have their own type (see [GetDriveType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdrivetypew) for details).

If you want ***exclusively*** USB drives, you'll need to call also [SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdeviceregistrypropertyw) with **SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY** property before accepting the drive, I've left a comment to where you should insert it if needed.

```c
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fileapi.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// Return a list of removable devices like GetLogicalDrives
// Bit 0=drive A, bit 26=drive Z.
// 1=removable drive, 0=everything else.
DWORD getRemovableDrives()
{
    DWORD result = 0u ;
    DWORD curr = 0u ;
    // Found all existing drives.
    if ((curr=GetLogicalDrives())) {
        TCHAR root[3] = TEXT("A:") ;
        int idx = 1 ;
        // Parse drives.
        for (int i=0;i<26;i++, idx<<=1) {
            // If drive present, check it..
            if ( (curr & idx) && (GetDriveType(root)==DRIVE_REMOVABLE) )
                // Drive is removable (can be USB, CompactFlash, SDCard, ...).
                // Call SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW here if needed.
                result |= idx ;
            root[0]++ ;
        }
    }
    return result ;
}

int main()
{
    DWORD removableDrives = getRemovableDrives() ;
    int count = 0 ;
    _tprintf(TEXT("Current removable drive(s):\n\t")) ;
    for (int i=0 ; i<26 ; i++)
        if (removableDrives & (1<<i)) {
            _tprintf(TEXT("%c: "),_T('A')+i) ;
            count++ ;
        }
    _tprintf(TEXT("\nFound %d removable drive(s).\n"),count) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Current removable drive(s):
    K: N: 
Found 2 removable drive(s).
```

The main function, `getRemovableDrives()`, is obviously fully silent and does not produce any output. The `main()` only shows how to parse its results. The function is pretty fast, therefore you can call it without impacting too much performances - but it would be better to get notifications about drives connection/disconnection anyway.

Error checking is at minimal level, and my Unicode C is a bit rusted so they may be some space for some little more optimizations.